# NetBeans - Restful Web Service - JoinColumn

Tags: rest, join, netbeans

I'm new to Java coding, NetBeans and Web services.

I' ve followed this link (http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RESTfulWebServices/RESTfulWebservices.htm?cid=6173&ssid=108887617423702#s6) to make my own web service.

I have two tables OWNER and HOUSE, and many-to-one relationship (foreign-key OWNER_ID in HOUSE). However I do not know how to join HOUSE while creating OWNER in @GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add foreign keys to tables in database, after generate New->"RESTful web services from Database" all relation will be generated by default. If you do a

```
@GET
@Override
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<House> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}
```

The Owner of the House will be included automatically

Comment: Thanks! Adding the foreign key (using an alter table) after creating the entities in Netbeans saved me much of the problems related to Persistance and SQL Violations